# Connection to Mongo DB Atlas using Elixir

Tags: mongodb, elixir

I am trying to connect to Mongo Atlas using just Elixir mongo driver.

I wish there were enough help or code snippets around for making these external sharded connections with replica sets. Here's the error I've been receiving:

```
Mongo.Protocol (#PID<0.303.0>) failed to connect: ** (Mongo.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
```

Connection start_link:

```
conn = Mongo.start_link( 
 database: "admin", 
 seeds: [
  "server-shard-01:27017", 
  "server-shard-02:27017", 
  "server-shard-03:27017" 
 ], 
 set_name: "test-shard-0", 
 username: "myuser", 
 password: "mypassword", 
 auth_source: "admin", 
 port: 27017, 
 type: "replica_set_primary", 
 ssl: true 
)
```

I couldn't find any Erlang libraries helping here either. This could actually be due to the underlying Erlang libraries.

So alternatively we have implemented a Ruby code that does the writes to MongoDB and it runs as a separate container. Even though Elixir would let us run Ruby this is still not the best performing.

I would like to know if anyone else has found a solution for this yet?

Comment: removing ruby tag since it's not really relevant to solving your issue

Comment: What specific MongoDB driver and version are you using with Elixir? To make sure this isn't an IP whitelist / firewall issue, are you able to connect to your deployment from the same source IP using the `mongo` shell?

Comment: Is your cluster setup actually sharded, or is it just replica sets? The [`mongodb`](https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb) driver does not currently support shards. Aside from that, you have not really given much information here for us to try to solve the issue. The only issue I see with your configuration is that the value for the `:type` key should be an atom, not a string, but that would not lead to this error. *disclaimer:* I am the current maintainer for the mongodb package.

Comment: @Stennie We're using :mongodb, "0.3.0". Also able to connect to the Mongo atlas url using the Ruby driver on the same server instance. @

Comment: Also @JustinWood the server has replica sets. We tried a local replicaset, as well and we had issues when the primary changes. Does this mean that there's no solution currently using elixir or erlang? The URL also requires ssl, am just looking for the best possible way to handle this inside the elixir app.

Comment: Replica set support was only added in v 0.4.0. Try updating the driver.

Comment: Sorry, looks like a Erlang SSL handshake failure issue with connecting to Mongo Atlas. @JustinWood has already mentioned here: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-December/091181.html

Comment: That issue was fixed with OTP 19.3.